# Dialog box to abort a while-loop in C++/CLI

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I have a while loop executed in a function. While the loop is executed, I would like to have a dialog box with an "Abort" button to show up on the screen on Windows. If I press the Abort button, the program would terminate the while loop. It's like a dialog which pops up when a file is copied. Could anybody suggest a simple way to do this with C++/CLI or something similar?

Since I don't have a lot of experience with C++/CLI, I would appreciate if you could provide me with code snippets or sample codes.

Comment: You'll need to use a thread for this to work.  Use BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

Using a separate thread is the modern way to do this, but there is another approach.

You can take the guts of your while loop and put them in an event handler.  Arrange to have the message loop call this event handler again and again until the job it done (e.g., with a timer or idle processing).  In the mean time, you can display a non-modal pop-up dialog.  This is how printing used to work in the pre-emptive multitasking era.  See [SetAbortProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'd recommend that second thread approach listed by others.  I just wanted to point out that it's not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of the `while` loop is the easy part. What makes it hard is you'll have to put the abort dialog in a different thread and then coordinate a flag in the `while` condition with the dialog. This is usually handled with semaphores which are known to be difficult to code without subtle side-effects.

The `while` loop, at a minimum, will need to have a mechanism that allows the event queue to get processed AND periodically checks for a change in the status of the abort semaphore.

```
//psuedo-code below
bool f_abort = false;
while (!f_abort)
{
    do_partial_work();
    f_abort = checkForAbort();
    sleep(0); // don't want to lock the CPU
}
```

I'm not an expert in threads so I'll have to point you to other resources for what to do in `checkForAbort()`.

[Windows Forms Threading and Events - ListBox updates promptly but progressbar experiences huge delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095/windows-forms-threading-and-events-listbox-updates-promptly-but-progressbar-ex)

[Win32 synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718344/win32-synchronization)

[Is putting thread on hold optimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131818/is-putting-thread-on-hold-optimal)

[Thread for Windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638991/thread-for-windows-form)

Answer (score -1):

One simple (but poor) example could be this one:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Threading;

DialogResult *res=new DialogResult(DialogResult::No);

void waitForUserAction()
{
    while(*res==DialogResult::No)
    {
    *res=System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Exit the loop ? YES/NO","TEST",
                MessageBoxButtons::YesNo,MessageBoxIcon::Question);
    if(*res==DialogResult::Yes)
        Console::WriteLine(L"Exit by user");
    }
}

int main()
{

    ThreadStart ^start=gcnew ThreadStart(waitForUserAction);
    Thread ^pThread=gcnew Thread(start);
    int a=0;

    pThread->Start();
    while(*res!=DialogResult::Yes)
    {
        a=a+1;
        Console::WriteLine(L"Loop processing here...{0}",a);
    }
    //pThread->Abort();
    return 0;
}
```

You can check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/managedsafethreads.aspx) for more info on the topic...

Comment: Please don't use `Thread.Abort()` to manage the flow of an application. It's dangerous and should be used only when really necessary, which is not the case here.

Comment: @ildjarn: You can only access GUI objects from the thread which created them, but it's perfectly possible to have multiple UI threads.

Comment: @Ben : I'll concede that you likely know more about this than I, but I was under the strong impression that WinForms specifically has the requirement of a single STA thread.

Comment: @ildjarn: Just tested it and works fine as expected.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6919979/TwoUIThreads.7z

Comment: @Ben : You're right, the `MessageBox` docs explicitly say that its static members are uniformly thread-safe.

Comment: Since I am not very familiar with multithreading, I don't quite understand the discussion here. Could anybody explain what the issue here is?